# Simulating data for Spline Regression

Tags: simulation, splines

I am making some simulation in order to show the performance of the Spline Regression vs other methods like Smoothing Splines, Hodric Prescott filter, etc., I would like to knot if it's better to sample the dependent variable $X$ out of a uniform distribution rather than fixing them to be equidistant. 
I know that it depends on what I want to do, if I am trying to approximate a signal that is sampled each 1 second, then the observations will be equidistant, but is it better to test the performance in  a more general case to sample $X$ ?

Comment: That's going to depend entirely upon your application area.  The key question is: what does your actual data look like?  If it's sampled each second, as you say, then you'll learn more from your simulation study by duplicating that than by constructing $X$ in some other way.

Comment: Just a comment, I would not use HP filter with a non-equidistant X.